# Let $g(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ . Which of $\frac{a}{b},\frac{a}{c}$, and $\frac{a}{d}$ cannot be in the domain of $g^{-1} $

Tags: functions

Let $$g(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$ where $a,b,c,$ and $d$ are positive and $ad \ne bc $. Which of $\frac{a}{b},\frac{a}{c}$, and $\frac{a}{d}$ cannot be in the domain of $g^{-1}$?

I've found that $$g^{-1}=\cfrac{dx-b}{a-cx}$$ after that I've tried each of $\frac{a}{b},\frac{a}{c}$, and $\frac{a}{d}$ but I didn't find any constraint on them.

The hint from my book says to express $g^{-1}$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$ and that's what I've done but I don't see now how the solution jumps out of it

Comment: **HINT**: Observe what happens to the denominator of $g^{-1}$ when $x=\frac{a}{c}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $$g^{-1}(x)=\cfrac{dx-b}{a-cx}$$ is not defined for $x=a/c$ since the denominator becomes  $0$.

Comment: Shame on me,I don't even know what I was thinking. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1):

The equation
$$
\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}=y
$$
becomes
$$
(a-cy)x=dy-b
$$
When does the equation $Ax=B$ have a single solution?